# Custom Listview showing no images at certain rows

Tags: android

I have a a baglist of items with me.Which has name,price and productimage url.
I use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader  this library to load the imageview from the url.The problem i face is the  listview doesnt show images at certain rows

```
public class BagAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int pos;

    Context MyContext;
    public boolean isCloseButtonAvailable;
    Object positionForCheck;
    ViewHolderForBag holder;

    public BagAdapter(Context _MyContext, boolean isavail) {

        MyContext = _MyContext;
        isCloseButtonAvailable = isavail;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return BagList.getItemCount();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View MyView = convertView;
        pos = position;
        positionForCheck = (Object) pos;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) MyContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.shoppingbagrow, null);
            holder = new ViewHolderForBag();
            holder.listitemimageView = (ImageView) MyView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listitemimageView);
            holder.name = (TextView) MyView
                    .findViewById(R.id.DescriptionTextView);
            holder.price = (TextView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.PriceTextView);
            holder.arrowimage = (ImageView) MyView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Arrowimagelistitem);
            holder.editimage = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.editimage);
            holder.border = (ImageView) MyView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listitemimageView);

            MyView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolderForBag) MyView.getTag();
        }

        String producturl="";
        Typeface type= Typeface.createFromAsset(MyContext.getAssets(),"fonts/Helvetica.ttf");

        holder.name.setText("$"
                + BagList.getAllBaglistItems().get(pos).itemName);

        holder.price.setText("$"
                + BagList.getAllBaglistItems().get(pos).itemPrice);
        Double d=Double.parseDouble(BagList.getAllBaglistItems().get(pos).itemPrice.toString());

producturl=String.valueOf(BagList.getAllBaglistItems().get(pos).itemUrl.toString());



    holder.price.setText( String.format("%.2f", d) );
    holder.price.setTypeface(type, Typeface.BOLD);
    holder.name.setTypeface(type, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.arrowimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.aero);

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(MyContext));
        imageLoader.displayImage(producturl, holder.listitemimageView );

        holder.editimage.setTag(pos);

        if ((position + 1) % 3 == 0)
            holder.border.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else
            holder.border.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (isCloseButtonAvailable) {
            holder.editimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.editimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    DatabaseAdapterForBag dbBag = new DatabaseAdapterForBag(
                            MyContext);
                    dbBag.open();

                    int posi = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                    dbBag.deleteFile(BagList.getAllBaglistItems().get(posi).itemSku);
                    dbBag.close();
                    BagList.deleteItem(posi);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.editimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return MyView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolderForBag {

        // public ImageView listitemimageView;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView price;
        public ImageView border;
        public ImageView arrowimage;
        public ImageView editimage;
        public ImageView listitemimageView;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return BagList.getAllBaglistItems().get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {

        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


}
```

This is my adapter class.WHere am i doing wrong?

Comment: try downloading those images from the link on your pc... there might be some problem with those links...

Comment: No the links are fine.i tried it in browser its fine

Comment: your code looks ok...I mean I couldn't find any bug in the code. Is the problem recurrent with the same list item or it is random??

Comment: I have the option to remove the item from the list.Suppose i have 3 items in the listview.lets say 2nd row misses the image.Now if i remove the 3rd item from the list view.(im calling  notifyDataSetChanged();
 in it)Then it will show the image.Its weird and confusing.

Comment: after you remove the 3rd item then the second item displays the correct image that it is supposed to display at this position??

Comment: yea then it shows the image.Before it doesnt show that image at 2nd row when the 3rd item was there..funny thing is image doesnt show in 3,6,9 th locations..i checked with 9 elements

Comment: You are changing some view visibility if it at the position which is a multiple of 3...I don't know what is the purpose of this but this could be the reason

Comment: yea that was the problem.Actually i have a similar page with gridview,which has 3 columns in row,I had to do some calculation on the 3rd item to show it properly,Here i dont need that part.Thank you so much for finding that.